# SQLAlchemy | How to query and filter only variables that are not Null (or None)?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm having all these variables which are inputs from my program as below:

```
    invoice_number 
    trading_partner_name
    invoices_added_date_from 
    invoices_added_date_to 
    invoices_date_from 
    invoices_date_to 
    payment_status
```

And I have an sqlite table called Invoice that hold multiple information about the invoices. I want to create one query that can filter using all variables above that is not None (or Null). Something like below:

```
query_all = s.query(Invoice).filter_by((invoice_number=invoice_number and invoice_number != None),(trading_partner_name=trading_partner_name and trading_partner_name != None), (...and invoices_added_date_from != None),(...),(...)).all()
```

But I really don't know how to do this in SQLAlchemy/Python...

My codes for the Invoice table are as below:

```
class Invoice(Base):
    __tablename__ = "invoice"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)

    trading_partner_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("trading_partner.id"))
    trading_partner_name = Column(String, ForeignKey("trading_partner.trading_partner_name"))


    id_relationship = relationship('TradingPartner', backref='tradingid', foreign_keys=[trading_partner_id])
    name_relationship = relationship('TradingPartner', backref='tradingname', foreign_keys=[trading_partner_name])

    invoice_number = Column(String)

    invoice_date = Column(String)

    invoice_amount = Column(String)

    invoice_currency = Column(String)

    invoice_added_date = Column(String)

    tax = Column(Integer)
    description = Column(String)
    expired_contract_date = Column(String)

    actual_payment_date = Column(String)

    actual_payment_accepted_by = Column(String)
    overdue_period = Column(Integer)
    notes_for_penalty_overdue = Column(String)
    paid = Column(Float)

    paid_amount = Column(Integer)

    payment_unpaid_amount = Column(Integer)
    payment_date1 = Column(String)
    payment_date2 = Column(String)
    occurent = Column(String)

    invoice_added_by_user = Column(String, ForeignKey("user.username"))
```

Could anyone pls help me? Thank you so much!
(I took 4 hours going through over 50 Stackoverflow questions, but I still don't know how to do it...)

Comment: I think my question is really about how to filter multiple criterias for one column during a query?

Comment: maybe a function within the query?

Comment: Instead of building the (attribute != None) logic in the query, you can filter out these None attrs before the query itself i.e query only attributes which have some input value.

Comment: Yes.But it would take quite a lot of if else statements. I was just wondering if there is anyway quicker. But thank you!:)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of building None logic in the query, can filter these None attributes before the query itself.

```
filter_params = {
   "invoice_number": invoice_number,
   "trading_partner_name": trading_partner_name
}
base_query = s.query(Invoice)

for field, value in filter_params.items():
    if value is None:
       continue
    base_query = base_query.filter_by(getattr(Invoice, field) = value)

query_all = base_query.all()


# note: this solution doesn't handle querying with
# multiple operators, >=, <, in_ ...
# more generic solution is to build a generic query
# builder method using Operator class from sqlalchemy
```